# Xamarin Forms: Scroll to is not working when reversing the collection data

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have 3 tabs on the top of the page where I am listing some data using `ListView`. When I tap on a tab I need to scroll to the end of the listview, I mean I need to scroll to the last item of the `ListView`. I am reversing the collection before setting it to the `ListView`. I used below codes to scroll to last item:

```
settingslistview.ScrollTo(tab1settingList[tab1settingList.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);
```

This is working fine if we not reverse the data. But when reversing the scrolling is not working.

I am adding the sample codes of my demo project below:

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ScrollToDemo.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Grid
            Margin="10,0,10,0"
            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="34*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackLayout
                Grid.Column="0"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Margin="2,0"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Orientation="Vertical">

                <Label 
                    x:Name="tab1_label"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    Text="Tab1"
                    Style="{StaticResource style1}"/>

                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="Tab1Tapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Margin="2,0" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Orientation="Vertical">

                <Label 
                    x:Name="tab2_label"
                    IsEnabled="False"
                    Text="Tab2"
                    Style="{StaticResource style1}"/>

                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="Tab2Tapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout
                Grid.Column="2"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Margin="2,0"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Orientation="Vertical">

                <Label 
                    x:Name="tab3_label"
                    IsEnabled="False"
                    Text="Tab3"
                    Style="{StaticResource style1}"/>

                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="Tab3Tapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>

        <ListView   
            x:Name="settingslistview"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            SelectionMode="None"
            SeparatorColor="#cecece"
            SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Frame
                                HasShadow="False"
                                Padding="8"
                                CornerRadius="{OnIdiom Phone=20, Tablet=30}"
                                BorderColor="#bdbdbd"
                                Margin="5"
                                BackgroundColor="{Binding BGColor}">

                                <StackLayout 
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <Label 
                                        Text="{Binding Title}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        TextColor="{Binding TextColor}">
                                        <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                <OnIdiom.Phone>18</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>27</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>18</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                            </OnIdiom>
                                        </Label.FontSize>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Frame.HeightRequest>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>30</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>45</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>30</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Frame.HeightRequest>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Footer>
                <Label/>
            </ListView.Footer>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ScrollToDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SettingPageItems> tab1settingList;
        public ObservableCollection<SettingPageItems> tab2settingList;
        public ObservableCollection<SettingPageItems> tab3settingList;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tab1settingList = new ObservableCollection<SettingPageItems>();
            tab2settingList = new ObservableCollection<SettingPageItems>();
            tab3settingList = new ObservableCollection<SettingPageItems>();
            Tab1Items();
            Tab2Items();
            Tab3Items();
        }

        private void Tab1Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tab1_label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
            tab2_label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None;
            tab3_label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None;
            settingslistview.ItemsSource = tab1settingList.Reverse();
            if (tab1settingList.Count != 0)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    settingslistview.ScrollTo(tab1settingList[tab1settingList.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);
                });
            }
        }

        private void Tab2Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tab1_label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None;
            tab2_label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
            tab3_label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None;
            settingslistview.ItemsSource = tab2settingList.Reverse();
            if (tab2settingList.Count != 0)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    settingslistview.ScrollTo(tab2settingList[tab2settingList.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);
                });
            }
        }

        private void Tab3Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tab1_label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None;
            tab2_label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None;
            tab3_label.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
            settingslistview.ItemsSource = tab3settingList.Reverse();
            if (tab3settingList.Count != 0)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    settingslistview.ScrollTo(tab3settingList[tab3settingList.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);
                });
            }
        }

        public void Tab1Items()
        {
            for(int i =1; i<= 20; i++)
            {
                tab1settingList.Add(new SettingPageItems() { Title = "Option"+i, BGColor = Color.FromHex("#e4e4e4"), TextColor = Color.Black });
            }
            settingslistview.ItemsSource = tab1settingList.Reverse();
        }

        public void Tab2Items()
        {
            for (int i = 21; i <= 40; i++)
            {
                tab2settingList.Add(new SettingPageItems() { Title = "Option" + i, BGColor = Color.FromHex("#FFEBEE"), TextColor = Color.Black });
            }
        }

        public void Tab3Items()
        {
            for (int i = 41; i <= 60; i++)
            {
                tab3settingList.Add(new SettingPageItems() { Title = "Option" + i, BGColor = Color.FromHex("#E8EAF6"), TextColor = Color.Black });
            }
        }
    }
}


public class SettingPageItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private Color bgColor;
    public Color BGColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                bgColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return bgColor;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private Color textColor;
    public Color TextColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                textColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return textColor;
        }
    }

    private string imageSource;
    public string ImageSource
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                imageSource = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return imageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ScrollToDemo.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="style1" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize">
                <OnIdiom
                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                    Phone="18"
                    Tablet="27"
                    Desktop="18"/>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have uploaded a sample demo [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rlJRtOx5FxrUfM_0eLbKxJdCNycd_hsg/view?usp=sharing). I need to scroll to the last item of the listview when switching to other tabs. Currently it is on top of the page when switching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following code:

```
    private void Tab1Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        settingslistview.ItemsSource = tab1settingList.Reverse();
        if (tab1settingList.Count != 0)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                settingslistview.ScrollTo(tab1settingList[tab1settingList.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);
            });
        }
    }
```

You use  `tab1settingList.Reverse();` and set it to ItemsSource. The Reverse method returns a reversed IEnumerable but it doesn't modify the origin collection. That means `tab1settingList`'s order is not changed. So when you use `scrollto` method, the last item in `tab1settingList` is still option20.

You may do something like this:

```
private void Tab1Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ObservableCollection<SettingPageItems> reversedtab1settingList = new ObservableCollection<SettingPageItems>(tab1settingList.Reverse());


    settingslistview.ItemsSource = reversedtab1settingList;
    if (tab1settingList.Count != 0)
    {
     
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            settingslistview.ScrollTo(reversedtab1settingList[reversedtab1settingList.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);
        });
    }
}
```

For more info, you may refer to [Enumerable.Reverse(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Linq_Enumerable_Reverse__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__)

Hope it helps!